# NO_APPLICABLE_PROCESS, No applicable approval process was found, yet the criteria is met, no code change in years

Tags: apex, dml, approval-process

Having an odd issue in our prod org recently. Code and approval items haven't changed, yet for some reason after our last monthly release we've been getting the no_applicable_process error here.

The process is basically a button is pressed and code tied to a vf page is executed, lead fields are updated, then its submitted through approval.process().

Adding some logging in our test sandbox right after update lead, and the update is successful and system.debug of the query for this lead id shows its been modifieddate is recent and the fields for the criteria are correct...

```
L.field__c=true;
L.field2__c='test';

update L;

Lead l2 = [select id,field__c,field2__c from lead where id=:L.id);
System.debug('L: '+l2); // results look good here. fields match criteria

Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest appReq = new Approval.ProcessSubmitRequest();
            appReq.setObjectId(L.id);
Approval.ProcessResult ap = Approval.process(appReq);
```

But I get

```
WF_PROCESS_FOUND||No applicable approval process was found.
```

And when I query for this record in dev console, the modifieddate is back in 2018, not recent. The changed fields were also not updated so some sort of rollback has happened (Think this is related to DML rollback after exception? Although I thought thats only on triggers) , but I don't see it in logs...

I tried to force the approval process with setProcessDefinitionNameOrId(), but I still get...

```
WF_PROCESS_FOUND|ProcessDefinitionNameOrId:-------|The process was invalid or didn't meet the required criteria.
```

I checked the profiles but didn't notice any issue. initial submitter is lead owner which is what the user is.

Really wish it was more specific on why it failed, in terms of criteria.

Heck I didn't get anything from here...

```
if(ap.isSuccess())
                    {
                        System.debug('successful id:');
                    }
                 else
            {
                for(Database.Error err : ap.getErrors()) {
                            System.debug('The following error has occurred.');                   
                            System.debug(err.getStatusCode() + ': ' + err.getMessage());
                            System.debug('Account fields that affected this error: ' + err.getFields());
                        }
            }
```

I assume if no criteria is met, it doesn't even get to this step?

Haven't found anything online related to my situation, so if any advice or guidance would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: you could use setup audit trail to see what changes you introduced in your latest release to give a clue.

Comment: Yep will be digging into that... but i'm not even sure what can be the issue here if it doesn't throw an obvious error in my logs even at the finest details.

Comment: Running user FLS issue on entry criteria to approval process?

Comment: Shouldn't be. The dlm update was successful and i queried right after to check. Think there might be something else related to this. So I completely removed the entry criteria and executed the button again... and still the same error... so for some reason this partner super user can't find this approval process at all?

Comment: it is a partner user?  Not an internal user?  Check https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=approvals_create_submitters.htm&type=5 for permissions on who can submit to an approval process

Comment: yeah partner. Something else discovered. ownerid for the Lead was assigned to a queue before the update. Seems like that would mess with 'Initial Submitters Lead Owner' on the approval process... but then i'm confused how this code worked for the last 3 years without an issue?